# Debug have Cancer on Android Studio (Variables debug info not available)

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, intellij-idea

For the love of God... For all the holy things we love...
I ask, I beg, I need help.

Cause I'm almost giving up this project.

Cause I'm almost unninstalling Android Studio forever.

Cause I'm almost giving up developing Android apps.

I've searched some solutions but never worked...

**FOR GOD, WHY THE DEBUG STOPS WORKING WITHOUT ANY REASON?**

[image]

Comment: I'm desperately begging for help, and all that good developers here know how to do is to -1 in my question...

Comment: Does it "stop working" in the same setup/environment? If so, describe it to give more possibilities for answers.

Comment: Man, in this time I continued to solve this and in the end i've reinstalled everything here. The problem has solved. Thanks...

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall everything (Android SDK, Android Studio) was the only solution I've found...